# Carcolh and the Earthlion

Tags: logical-deduction

While running from an angry Carcolh, you happen to run into an Earthlion guarding its hoard. This is a species known for overblown emotional displays: When stolen from, they turn purple in rage. When shown a greater value of gold, they turn green with envy. Fear turns them yellow, whereas they swell red with pride when gifted gold. Tickling, also, turns them pink. Furthermore, their memory is easily clouded, with them quickly forgetting the sources of their losses and gains

If your knowledge of Carcolh language is correct, a signal of green-red-purple-pink should serve as a sufficient apology

You have a wheelbarrow on you, which should hold just over 50 gold coins. The Earthlion has about 100 coins in her hoard

Given this, how can you get the Carcolh off your back?

Comment: Interesting backstory, haha. So the puzzle is to find a sequence of actions that make Earthlion to change into a sequence of colors, containing a consecutive subsequence of green-red-purple-pink, right?

Comment: @justhalf Yes, that's right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that stealing is the most appropriate way to effect an apology. But if you're going to, then here's a way to do so:

> Steal 51 coins (purple) and show them back to the Earthlion (green). Give two back to her (red) and steal one again (purple). Then tickle her (pink).

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that we don't have 50 coins in our wheelbarrow in the beginning. Was confused with your answer at first. Good one!